# Space to the right of each list element

Tags: html, css, html-lists, spacing

Not sure why there is a space to the right of each li, as you can see here when you mouse over it. Obviously don't want it there and can't figure out how to get rid of it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: problem]

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<header>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <nav class="nav-items" role="navigation">           
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">list1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">list2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">list3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>          
  </div>        
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  background-color:#2C5463;
  height:2.3em;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  }

header .nav-container {
  margin: 0 30px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  }

.nav-items {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-items ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-items ul li {
  display: inherit;
  border-left: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-items ul li a {
  display: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;  
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%; /* Width and height of top-level nav items */
  width: 90px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav-items ul li:hover {
  background: #617F8A
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eF83x/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needs to changes on css class here for your solution,

```
.nav-items ul 
{
    display: **inline-table**;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Demostration](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantsachaniya/bhar5/)

Answer (score 3):

Inline elements are sensitive to white space. Remove the white space and the problem goes away.

Ex:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">list1</a></li><li><a href="#">list2</a></li><li><a href="#">list3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eF83x/1/)**

You can remove the spaces between the list items literally, occupy the space with HTML comments (`<!-- -->`), or float them left.

Answer (score 0):

What you could also do is make the lis float left and display them as block. This will fix it without messing with the html code.

```
.nav-items ul li {
float: left;
display: block;
border-left: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/eF83x/2/)